# Creating events or listeners laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a very peculiar problem.The premise of it is, I have simulated a real time clock in javascript. The code is quite long but here is a snippet:

<! -- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -- >

<! -- language: lang-js -- >

```
function display_c() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
}

function display_ct6() {
  var x = new Date()
  var ampm = x.getHours() >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM';
  hours = x.getHours() % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
  var x1 = x.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getFullYear();
  x1 = x1 + " - " + hours + ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + x.getSeconds() + ":" + ampm;
  document.getElementById('ct6').innerHTML = x1;
  display_c6();
}

function display_c6() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout('display_ct6()', refresh)
}
display_c6()
```

```html
<span id='ct6' style="background-color: #FFFF00"></span>
```

I want to apply the above function to a php app. In this php app, I have a database with various fields . It stores two main tasks; start and stop . There is a timestamp field, which corresponds to each event. Whenever my app runs, my JS clock should begin at 7Am, irrespective of the system internal clock(This can be done).

```
myTask  Interval 
START   10(secs)
STOP    20(secs
```

Using my clock to check the intervals, how can I approach this so that I have N start_tasks running with respect to the START interval ,where N in a random int between 1 and 5 ?

Basically,I don't want to convert the code. Start and stop are more 'event timestamp trackers'. Whenever the application runs, I want a php function which will generate a random amount of n servers at a predetermined interval

```
PROGTIME   EVENT    MESSAGE          ACTUALTIME     DISPLAYMESSAGE 
12:00:10   START    Start 16 servers 10:00:30am     12:00:10 - start 16 servers 
12:00:20   STOP      Stop 10 servers 10:00:20am     12:00:20 - stop 10 servers
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the PHP part. Do you want to convert the code to PHP or just Ajax the start and stop to the server at intervals? What ARE start and stop?

Comment: @mplungjan  This illustration might help .                            PROGTIME EVENT MESSAGE ACTUALTIME DISPLAYMESSAGE 

12:00:10 START Start 16 servers 10:00:30am 12:00:30 - start 16 servers 
12:00:20 STOP Stop 10 servers 10:00:40am 12:00:40 - stop 10 servers

Comment: I hoped the above text would display  properly. Basically,I don't want to convert the code . Its more of your second point. Start and stop are more 'event timestamp trackers'. Whenever the application runs, I want a php function which will generate a random amount of n servers at a predetermined interval .

Comment: @mplungjan. I have added some illustration. Can you share your insights? Because of the interval, I can predict when the next due is. A function, which, at 07:00:00, log n servers started where n is  a random value between 1 & 5:

Answer (score 0):

It will be very hard to get 10 seconds on the dot. But yeah, you can add

```
var x = new Date(); 
if (x.getSeconds()%10==0) // every 10 seconds
  fetch(`/server.php?time=${x.getTime()}&rnd=${Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1}`)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));`
```